# GridLayout panel with buttons and JRadioButton on the second panel problem

Tags: java, swing

I've got problem with JRadioButton, JCheckBox and other similar components. I have pane with 9 Buttons and second pane with group of JRadioButtons. When i mouse over JRadioButton or if i select one it appears on the second buttonPane. I was looking for answer but i clearly don't know how to name my problem.

Frame code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("TicTacToe");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
    PlayButton b1 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b1);
    PlayButton b2 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b2);
    PlayButton b3 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b3);
    PlayButton b4 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b4);
    PlayButton b5 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b5);
    PlayButton b6 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b6);
    PlayButton b7 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b7);
    PlayButton b8 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b8);
    PlayButton b9 = new PlayButton();
    buttonPane.add(b9);

    JPanel chosePane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
    frame.add(chosePane, BorderLayout.EAST);
    chosePane.add(new JLabel("Chose symbol which starts game:  "));
    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    JRadioButton rb1 = new JRadioButton("First");
    JRadioButton rb2 = new JRadioButton("Second");
    group.add(rb1);
    group.add(rb2);
    chosePane.add(rb1);
    chosePane.add(rb2);
    frame.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

and Button code:

```
public class PlayButton extends JButton

 public PlayButton()
{
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
    //this.setBorder();
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.drawLine(4,4,95,95);
    g2.drawLine(4,95,95,4);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.drawLine(4,4,95,95);
    g2.drawLine(4,95,95,4);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
}
```

When you do custom painting you need to invoke

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

as the first statement in the method to make sure the background gets cleared otherwise painting artifacts can be left behind.

Of course if you do this, then you will get the default painting of a JButton. So maybe you need to extend JComponent for your custom painting?

Also, don't invoke repaint() in the constructor of your class:

1. it does nothing because the component hasn't been added to a visible frame
2. Swing will determine when a component needs to be repainted so you would rarely invoke this method unless you are doing something like animation and you need a component to repaint itself.

Edit:

Looks like you are just trying to draw an "X" on the button. You really shouldn't extend JButton for something like this. You should only extend a component when you add new functionality.

A `JButton` already supports the display of an `Icon`, so what you really want to do is just create an `Icon` that you can use on the button:

```
BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = bi.createGraphics();
g2.setColor( Color.BLACK );
g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
g2.drawLine(4,4,95,95);
g2.drawLine(4,95,95,4);
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon( bi );
```

Now the Icon can be used on any component that supports the display of an Icon:

```
JButton button = new JButton( icon );
button.setFocusPainted( false );
button.setBorder( null );
```

Comment: Yea it works, and default paiting of a JButton don't bother me. And this repaint() is a obvious mistake. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @HoldenFord, you really should not be extending a JButton. See the edit for a better solution.

Comment: I wanted to repaint the button after pressing it, but like u mensioned before i used this repaint wrongly. I agree that correct solution is add the icon after pressing the button. But i shoudn't draw this icon in paintComponent am i right? Btw i understand now fully what super does.

Comment: `add the icon after pressing the button.` - Why would you add it after pressing the button. Painting the Icon is the normal state of the button. You add the Icon when you create the button as I demonstrated in the code.

Comment: It will be TicTacToe game, so after pressing button i want X or Circle :)